# Swift 3: can you store code in variable then run it on tableview load?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have created a `UITableView` that pulls data from php mysql and passes data back in JSON format. In one of my variables passed in JSON format it's going to contain the value of:

```
variable = "cell.username.text = signupDate as String"
```

Is it possible and if so how would I run this variable so that its value '"cell.username.text = signupDate as String"` would run like it normally would if it wasn't inside the variable?

I hope this makes sense and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

**What Im Specifically Trying To Accomplish**

**MySQL :** Data stored as interests separated by commas.

*Ex:* "Outdoors, Coding, Videogames, etc."

**Reformat Interest in PHP :** Before sent as JSON to swift I will reformat interests

*Note: I am using a cocoa pod called Tag List View*

interests **variable** = "cell.interestsTag.addTag(“ Outdoors”); cell.interestsTag.addTag(“ Coding”); cell.interestsTag.addTag(“ Videogames”);"

**Swift3 :** Receive JSON variable as

var **variable** : NSString = (membersArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "**variable**") as! NSString

**when I print variable I get exactly what I want:**

*cell.interestsTag.addTag(“ Outdoors”); cell.interestsTag.addTag(“ Coding”); cell.interestsTag.addTag(“Videogames”);*

This is code inside the variable that needs to be run inside of my tableviewcell. Just can't figure out how to run the variable so it runs the code inside. If its even possible.

Comment: Why are you passing code as a `String`? Why not use functions?

Comment: It's runtime coding. If you can do this, you can invent a script language.

Comment: Actually you can passing arguments to a function. Make a function like func processmyString(a:String -> cell { } which returns a cell type object then you cell = self.processmyString(string) ... you need to split "cell.username.text = signupDate as String"  by = then first part needs to be used for your custom cell properties and the second part will actually be string. Hope this will help you.